# Ajax separate data which came from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am doing an ajax call like this:

```
                function myCall() {
                var request = $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    type: "GET",           
                    dataType: "html"
                });

                request.done(function(data) {
                    $("image").attr('src',data);   


                });

                request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );

                });         
            }
```

This is my ajax.php:

```
 <?php
 $connection = mysql_connect ("",
 "", "");

 mysql_select_db("");

// QUERY NEW ONE
$myquery = "SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($myquery);
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
$currentid = "$row->id";
$currentname = "$row->name";
$currenturl = "$row->url";
$currentimage = "$row->image";
echo  $currenturl,$currentnam, $currenturl,$currentimage;

}

mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

My data variable from the ajax call now contains all variables at once:

```
($currenturl,$currentnam, $currenturl,$currentimage)
```

How can I separate them so I can do something like:

```
 request.done(function(data) {
                $("id").attr('src',data1);   
                $("name").attr('src',data2); 
                $("url").attr('src',data3);   
                $("image").attr('src',data4); 

            });
```

Comment: As a beginner a keyword like 'json' means nothing to me..Could also be a serialkiller or a dog. thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery :

```
 $.ajax({

    type:"POST",
    url:"ajax.php",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(response){

    var url = response['url'];

    var name = response['name'];

    var image = response['image'];

   // Now do with the three variables



   // $("id").attr('src',data1);   
   // $("name").attr('src',data2); 
  //  $("url").attr('src',data3);   
   // $("image").attr('src',data4);

    },
    error:function(response){

    alert("error occurred");
    }

    });
```

From your code:

```
echo  $currenturl,$currentnam, $currenturl,$currentimage;
```

Replace the above line with the code below:

```
$array = array('url'=>$currenturl, 'name'=>$currentname, 'image'=>$currentimage);

echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: hm the ajax.php returns the right format. But the ajax call in the index.html does not work :/

Comment: my bad..nervermind :) everything works fine now. Thanks a thousand times!!

Answer (score 1):

instead of string return an array i.e. use json type for returning value

i.e instead of

```
echo  $currenturl,$currentnam, $currenturl,$currentimage;
```

use

```
echo json_encode array('current' => $currenturl,'currentnam' => $currentnam, 'currenturl' => $currenturl,'currentimage' => $currentimage);
```

and also write 'dataType' as 'json' in ajax

Comment: Now that is something i can work with. How can i access them in the ajax call? like data[1], data[2].. ?

Comment: No. you can access it with its key like, data.currentnam, data.currenturl and so on